# excel partial match in any of the lookup data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in column A and B have lookup data.

For A2 (FY|F|V|D|Safety|3M). take the B column first value and search whether there is any match if not take second value in B column and repeat the process for all the B column values and if there is match print the B column value in Result. Does that make sense?

I tried with VLOOKUP but no luck. Please help me.

Columns:

```
A                                  B(Lookup)            C(Result)
FY|F|V|D|Safety|3M                 Toro                 3M
FY|F|V|D|POP|ToroDays              3M                   Toro
FY|F|V|D|Lumber|GroundContact      honeywell            NA(Not available)
FY|F|V|D|airfilters|honeywell      samsung              honeywell
```

Comment: If you make the rows in column B into columns... You can do a search on each string... And if any of the columns are > 0 you have a found item..

Comment: Can you clarify your B and C columns? How is column C organized? Why is it `NA (not Available) for the third row?  If you're looking up `Toro` first, why is the first result `3M`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following formula in `Cell C2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(TRUE,IF(FIND($B$2:$B$5,A2)>0,TRUE),0)),"NA")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as required. Change range as needed.

See image for reference.

[image]

***NOTE :*** Above formula is case-sensitive. If you want non-case-sensitive result you can use following formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(TRUE,IF(FIND(UPPER($B$2:$B$5),UPPER(A2))>0,TRUE),0)),"NA")
```

Comment: Thanks Mrig for your reply. Formula is working but some places getting "0". 
FY17|FB|VF|D25H|Safety|3M         US       3M
FY17|FB|VF|D28I|POP|ToroDays US              0
FY17|FB|VF|D28I|POP|ToroDays WERNER     0                         
Formula I used: =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$400,MATCH(TRUE,IF(FIND($B$2:$B$400,A30)>0,TRUE),0)),"NA")

Comment: @ChaitanyaPhani - Is it possible for you to post a screen shot?

Comment: @Mirag - I have added a screen shot in one of the answer. Please refer. I was not able to attach the image in comments.

Comment: @ChaitanyaPhani - Firstly delete that answer, otherwise it will be downvoted. That is supposed to be a comment.

Comment: @ChaitanyaPhani - Do you have blank cells in loop up column?

Comment: @ChaitanyaPhani - Change `$B$2:$B$400` range to `$B$2:$B_` where `_` is last row with data.

Comment: Mrig - Is that is the reason am i getting "0" instead of value.

Comment: @ChaitanyaPhani - Probably yes. Kindly change the range and check.

Comment: I changed to =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B_,MATCH(TRUE,IF(FIND($B$2:$B_,A1)>0,TRUE),0)),"NA") getting the following error http://imgur.com/GNiPAqd

Comment: @ChaitanyaPhani - I wrote, replace `_` with the last row having data e.g. if data in `Column B` is till `B100` then write `$B$2:$B100`

Comment: Got It. Total B column have 388 rows. I entered "_" as 389th row in B column. And tried the formula =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B_,MATCH(TRUE,IF(FIND($B$2:$B_,A1)>0,TRUE),0)),"NA") but still getting same error.

Comment: @ChaitanyaPhani - Use `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B388,MATCH(TRUE,IF(FIND($B$2:$B388,A1)>0,TRU‌​E),0)),"NA")`

Comment: Mirg - I tried this and its working. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In `C2`, put this and drag down:

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH($B2,$A2)),"N/A",$B2)
```

Comment: not working. Need to search entire B column one by one whether it is matching or not. Its not straight forward.

Comment: @ChaitanyaPhani - What about `=IF(ISERR(VLOOKUP("*"&B1,$A$1:$A$4,1,FALSE),"N/A",B1)`?

Comment: it is giving "there is a problem with formula".

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tv0U7ghG74M_rtf5eX-secIrBXbg9lHgEW8Ory-H3Og/edit?usp=sharing) you go. A Google docs spreadsheet you can see.. The screenshots are from it.
Formulas
[image: Formulas]
Results
[image: Results]

You could have string with Toro3M in it, or all 4 for that matter.
The solution I have solves that. But you'd need to tweak to add commas or some such seperator.. And conditionally do it if cell in column F-I are zero length.

Comment: Thanks JGFMK for your reply. Is it not possible to do in a single column?

Comment: Well, if you resort to VBA I expect yes.. But I was trying to keep it simple, by flipping things around. Maybe someone else will reply, but it achieves your goal. You could also change output if blank to N/A or something to that effect too.

Comment: And you could concatenate in a single column... But you would have an extremely long formula. I find nesting IF statements painful to debug!